# Liquibase Windows MySQL - Cannot find database driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, windows, powershell, liquibase

I am running the following command in Powershell with a view to get it on CircleCI but am seeing the error: **Cannot find database driver: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver**

./liquibase.bat `--driver=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`
--classpath=E:\Software\liquibase-3.10.2\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar `--url="jdbc:mysql://REDACTED:3306/sandbox"`
--changeLogFile=/db.changelog-1.0.mysql.sql `--username=REDACTED`
--password=REDACTED `
generateChangeLog

I have checked the classpath of the mysql-connector file being correct / ran a file exists and is True

```
[System.IO.File]::Exists('E:\Software\liquibase-3.10.2\lib\mysql-connector-java-5.1.48.jar')
```

The PATH variable has the Liquibase root folder after checking the output of

```
$env:PATH
```

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change your driver to

```
--driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

or update your mysql dependency. I believe your dependency has package `com.mysql.jdbc` but [mysql updated](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-api-changes.html) their library with new package.

Try to use [this one](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.17) for example.

Comment: perfect - changing the driver param worked for me thanks

Comment: class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it worked when I added mysql dependency for the plugin:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.liquibase</groupId>
            <artifactId>liquibase-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>4.15.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <propertyFile>${liquibase.properties}</propertyFile>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                    <version>8.0.26</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```